# What determines the item order when converting a set to a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, set

I know there are several similar questions, but I haven't found one yet that talks about what I would like to know. If this is a duplicate, please point it out.

So I know a `set` in Python is an unordered collection, while a `list` can be sorted. What I am wondering about is what determins how the items of a list are ordered when the list was converted from a set.

Even though a set is 'technically' not sorted (which I guess just means that you cannot interact with it like you would with sequence types), there is still an order in the sense that when you print a set e.g., there has to be an item that is printed first, second, third and so on. This kind of logic needs to exist. But it goes even further than that. E.g. if you declare two sets in a 'scrambled' state that contain items that can be sorted, not only are their representations sorted when you execute them, the **union** of two 'scrabled' sets returns a 'sorted' set as well:

```
a = {2, 3, 1}
a
# >>> {1, 2, 3}
b = {7, 4, 5}
b
# >>> {4, 5, 7}

a|b  
# >>> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7} 
b|a
# >>> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7}
```

Also when you `add` a new item to a set and print the set, the new item appears in the correct place, i.e. the place where it should be if the set were sorted:

```
b.add(6)
b
# >>> {4, 5, 6, 7}
```

This brings me to my question. If you convert the sets to lists, something has to determine at what position each item of the set is placed in the new list. But it is appearently **NOT** the same logic that determines in which order the items are printed when executing a set, which is what I naively thought. While `list(a)`, `list(b)` and even `list(a|b)` all return lists that are sorted the way the sets are represented, for the following set (and all its permutations by the way), this is for some reason not the case:

```
list(a), list(b), list(a|b)
# >>> ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
c = {3, 4, 9}  # or {3, 9, 4}, {4, 3, 9} and so on...
c
# >>> {3, 4, 9}
list(c)  
# >>> [9, 3, 4]
```

Why is that? Why is the logic that determines in which way the representation of a set is ordered different from the one that determines where each item of a set goes when the set is converted to a list?

I tried a few more sets with different values, and to me, it seems completely random for when the order of the representation of the set and the order of the list of the set are the same:

```
# for this set of numbers, the logic is different
d = {3, 4, 11}
d
# >>> {3, 4, 11}
list(d)  
# >>> [11, 3, 4]

# in this case, permutations also result in different sorting of the list
d = {11, 4, 3}
d
# >>> {3, 4, 11}
list(d)  
# >>> [3, 11, 4]

# for this set, the logic appears to be the same again
e = {3, 4, 13}  # or any of its permutations
e
# >>> {3, 4, 13}
list(e)
# >>> [3, 4, 13]
```

The logic that determines the order of the list and calling `print(set)` seems to be the same:

```
list(d)  
# >>> [3, 11, 4]
print(d)
# >>> {3, 11, 4}
```

So I guess as soon as you *do* something with the set, a different sorting logic is applied. Unless of course, you create the union:

```
print(c, d, c|d, list(c|d))
# >>> {9, 3, 4} {3, 11, 4} {3, 4, 9, 11} [3, 4, 9, 11]
f = {3, 4, 9, 11}
f
# >>> {3, 4, 9, 11}
list(f)
# >>> [11, 9, 3, 4]
```

If you are wondering about the use case: as I said, I naively thought that the sorting would stay the same when converting a set to a list, when in reality, it does not. The wrong sorting caused an error when running my code. Luckily, it is easy to fix by using `sorted(set)` instead of `list(set)`, but it took some time to figure out the mistake in the first place.

So with this question I am trying to understand what is going on rather than looking for a solution.

Comment: This is likely an implementation detail. Are you specifically asking about CPython, the implementation available at https://www.python.org/?

Comment: Interesting! I am using Anaconda build version 3.18.11 with Python 3.7.7. if that is what you are asking?

Comment: I'm using vanilla `3.7.4` and my `repr(some_set)` is always the same order as `list(some_set)`.  I'm not able to recreate a case like your last example where `repr(f)` is different from `list(f)`.  Same goes for union sets.  Note that `repr({3, 11, 4})` is not the same as `repr({11, 3, 4})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on Python `3.7.4.` and all my `list(set)` order coincides with `repr(set)` order.  Here's a quick test [(code)](https://ideone.com/UEOJhy) on 10000 samples:

```
import random
import pandas as pd

# create a function to generate random set of 0-999 with len of 3 - 20
f = lambda: set(random.randrange(1000) for i in range(random.randrange(3, 21)))

# create a DataFrame of 10000 rows with random sets
df = pd.DataFrame({'sets': [f() for i in range(10000)]})

# Create a column of repr(set) and retrieve the order in str
df['reprs'] = df['sets'].apply(repr).str.strip('{}')

# Create a column of list(set) and retrieve the order in str
df['lists'] = df['sets'].apply(list).astype(str).str.strip('[]')

# Create a comparison column
df['match'] = df['reprs'].eq(df['lists'])

# Take a look of the reprs and lists...
print(df[['reprs', 'lists']])

# Summarize
summary = df.groupby('match')['sets'].count()
print(summary)
```

Results:

> ```
> match
> True    10000
> Name: sets, dtype: int64
> ```

So I'd imagine if anything you want to pay attention to how `set` is represented, which is an implementation detail per the initial comment.

Comment: Thanks for having a look! So does that mean for different Python environments you actually have different kinds of logics that apply? Why would that be? I mean why would there be a need to change these things?

Comment: Implementation detail changes can happen between versions, whether intentional or unintentional, same goes for the various different flavours of Python available.  An example would be `dict` also used to be unordered until `3.6` as an implementation detail, and only officially became insertion order in `3.7`.  I'm not that well versed in low level to understand these details, but if you are interested, check out the [Python source code](https://github.com/python/cpython).

Comment: While the answer is true, it doesn't actually answer the question... in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what OP observes is the effect of **interned** values.

Consider:

```py
>>> list({*range(2,99), True, False})
[False, True, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...]
```

However:

```py
>>> list({*range(2002,2099), True, False})
[2048, 2049, ..., True, False, ..., 2047]
```

Yet it doesn't fully explain OP's own observation:

```py
>>> list({3,4,9, True, False})
[False, True, 3, 4, 9]

>>> list({3,4,9})
[9, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input! That's some very interesting behaviour. I guess I'd need to ask on an official Python forum to get an answer.